# Finding Co-efficient of Variation for a Demand Planning use case using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

I need to calculate Demand Variability ( basically the Coefficient of Variation for Demand) for articles that I sell in my business. For most items, I have monthly demand for 12 months, and hence 12 data points that I can directly use Numpy to calculate the Std. Dev and Mean over the 12 months and get the Coeff of Variation. However, for certain articles, there is demand only over a few months, for e.g. 5 out of the 12 months. In those cases, I need to plug in Zero for the months in which there is no demand and calculate the Std. Deviation accordingly (so that the Std. Deviation is not underestimated). And this needs to be done over a million row dataset with individual articles. Is there a direct function to carry out this operation in Python? Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you need reindexing with fill value 0, where index is months. Sort of `df.reindex(index_with_all_months, fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading your data in Python and how are the empty values represented? (i.e. are they just null values or represented with other string e.g. "n/a"?)

**If you are using Pandas**, you may use the `.fillna` (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method. It'd be easier to answer if you could show a sample of the data.